# Cannot render polygon in React Map GL with data from API call

Tags: reactjs, polygon, geojson, vite, mapbox-gl

I successfully make a call to an API to get the GeoJson data, however when I set this as a variable , it reads that the data is an invalid GeoJson object. However, if I simply copy and paste the data into my code, the polygon appears on the map.

[This is how I call and set the data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck890.png)

[And this is how I intend to render it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vus46.png)

[This is how the data looks when received.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmXii.png)

Any help would be massively appreciated!